# feature label not work in xhtml file

Tags: jsf, xhtml, label, openlayers

I have a problem, I develop an jsf application with openlayers api, this example http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/vector-features-with-text.html work fine with html page, but when I change to xhtml page the label text doesn´t showing. I hope anyone can help me, Thanks for your time and help. Here is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"></meta>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"></meta>
<title>OpenLayers Labeled Features Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../openLayers/theme/default/style.css"
type="text/css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../openLayers/style.css" type="text/css"></link>
<script src="../openLayers/OpenLayers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;

function init(){
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');

    var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS", 
            "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0", {layers: 'basic'} );
    map.addLayer(layer);

    // allow testing of specific renderers via "?renderer=Canvas", etc
    var renderer = OpenLayers.Util.getParameters(window.location.href).renderer;
    renderer = (renderer) ? [renderer] : OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.prototype.renderers;

    var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Simple Geometry", {
        styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({'default':{
            strokeColor: "#00FF00",
            strokeOpacity: 1,
            strokeWidth: 3,
            fillColor: "#FF5500",
            fillOpacity: 0.5,
            pointRadius: 6,
            pointerEvents: "visiblePainted",
            // label with \n linebreaks
            label : "name: ${name}\n\nage: ${age}",

            fontColor: "${favColor}",
            fontSize: "12px",
            fontFamily: "Courier New, monospace",
            fontWeight: "bold",
            labelAlign: "${align}",
            labelXOffset: "${xOffset}",
            labelYOffset: "${yOffset}",
            labelOutlineColor: "white",
            labelOutlineWidth: 3
        }}),
        renderers: renderer
    });

    // create a point feature
    var point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(-111.04, 45.68);
    var pointFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point);
    pointFeature.attributes = {
        name: "toto",
        age: 20,
        favColor: 'red',
        align: "cm"
    };

    // create a polygon feature from a linear ring of points
    var pointList = [];
  //<![CDATA[
    for(var p=0; p<6; ++p) {
        var a = p * (2 * Math.PI) / 7;
        var r = Math.random(1) + 1;
        var newPoint = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(point.x + 5 + (r * Math.cos(a)),
                                                     point.y + 5 + (r * Math.sin(a)));
        pointList.push(newPoint);
    }
  //]]>
    pointList.push(pointList[0]);

    var linearRing = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LinearRing(pointList);
    var polygonFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
        new OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon([linearRing]));
    polygonFeature.attributes = {
        name: "dude",
        age: 21,
        favColor: 'purple',
        align: 'lb'
    };

    multiFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
        new OpenLayers.Geometry.Collection([
            new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString([
                new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(-105,40),
                new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(-95,45)
            ]),
            new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(-105, 40)
        ]),
        {
            name: "ball-and-chain",
            age: 30,
            favColor: 'black',
            align: 'rt'
        });

    // Create a point feature to show the label offset options
    var labelOffsetPoint = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(-101.04, 35.68);
    var labelOffsetFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(labelOffsetPoint);
    labelOffsetFeature.attributes = {
        name: "offset",
        age: 22,
        favColor: 'blue',
        align: "cm",
        // positive value moves the label to the right
        xOffset: 50,
        // negative value moves the label down
        yOffset: -15
    };


    var nullFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(null);
    nullFeature.attributes = {
        name: "toto is some text about the world",
        age: 20,
        favColor: 'red',
        align: "cm"
    };

    map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
    vectorLayer.drawFeature(multiFeature);
    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(-109.370078125, 43.39484375), 4);
    vectorLayer.addFeatures([pointFeature, polygonFeature, multiFeature, labelOffsetFeature, nullFeature ]);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<h1 id="title">OpenLayers Labeled features example</h1>
<div id="tags">
vector, feature, labeling, symbolizer, light
</div>
<p id="shortdesc">
Label vector features with a text symbolizer.
</p>
<div id="map" class="smallmap"></div>
<div id="docs">
<p>This example shows drawing simple vector features with a label.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try escaping the $ using a backslash:  `label : "name: \${name}\n\nage: \${age}"`